# Como fazer um script que gere uma cor de fundo aleatória no site?

Tags: javascript, css

Aqui está meu código, não sei o que está errado:

```js
var x = Math.random();

if (x < 0.5) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
} else {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `getElementsByTagName` retorna uma lista com todos os elementos `body` do documento, então você precisa definir qual elemento quer tratar. Neste caso, sendo o elemento `body`, só existirá um, então basta fazer:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
```

Ficando assim:

```js
var x = Math.random();

if (x < 0.5) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
} else {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
}
```

Porém, mais fácil que isso, você pode fazer apenas `document.body`, sem utilizar o `getElementsByTagName`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var x = Math.random();

if (x < 0.5) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
} else {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
}
```

Comment: A sua última solução funciona para qualquer tag??? ex.: document.div.style.background...

Comment: @nelson450 Não, apenas o `body`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, sou iniciante em JS

Answer (score 1):

Repare que a função utilizada está no plural `getElementsByTagName`
e por isso devolve um array de elementos em vez de um elemento. Pode alterar o seu código para atribuir a cor ao elemento 0 que será o primeiro e único fazendo:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
```

Exemplo:

```js
var x = Math.random();
if (x < 0.5) {
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
} 
else {
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
}
```

Alternativamente pode até gerar uma cor completamente aleatória se quiser, fazendo uso de rgb na atribuição da cor na forma de:

```
rgb(vermelho, verde, azul)
```

Em que cada uma das partes de cor vai de 0 a 255, sendo 0 vazia e 255 cheia.

```js
var vermelho = Math.round(Math.random()*255); //criar um numero de 0 a 255 e arredondar
var verde = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
var azul = Math.round(Math.random()*255);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + vermelho + "," + verde + "," + azul + ")";
```